# Cannot find type GIDSignInDelegate and property clientID with Google sign in with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I follow the guideline of firebase but when I enter code for client ID in `AppDelegate`, it not accept. Also it not accept the `GIDSignInDelegate` method.

[image]

Comment: Why not use Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `6.0.0` GoogleSignIn doesn't have a delegate anymore, they've switched to completions(probably to easily support new swift concurrency).

Check out [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide).

You can use it like this now, in your view controller:

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
    with: "clientId",
    presenting: self // your view controller
) { user, error in
    if let token = user?.authentication.idToken {
        completionHandler(token, nil)
        return
    }
    guard let error = error as? GIDSignInError else { 
        fatalError("No token and no GIDSignInError: \(String(describing: error))") 
    }
    completionHandler(nil, error)
}
```

In your `AppDelegate` you need this(just like before):

```swift
func application(
    _ app: UIApplication,
    open url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]
) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(openURL)
}
```

Comment: This code use in App Delegate or Viewcontroller?

Comment: @ShubhamShinde yes, check out updated answer